# jQuery unbind on hover, re-enable on hover-off

Tags: jquery, hover

I am dispalying a caption when a div is hovered over, I want to disable the effect when the mouse remains over the div.... so the user has to mouse-off before the caption will display again. I can didsable this with unbind but the problem is it kills the mouse-off 
function:

```
$('.lowerFrontStripRow img').hover(         

function(){
     $('.orbit-caption-bottom#bottomThumb'+$(this).data("thumbid")).slideDown();
     $('.lowerFrontStripRow img').unbind();
},

function(){
     $('.lowerFrontStripRow img').bind(hover);
     $('.orbit-caption-bottom').slideUp();

}

);
```

How can i disable until the mouse off action?

Thanks,

Alan.

Comment: Should be a better way of doing what you expect. You should provide more relevant code as HTML markup and maybe a jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Only this should work

```
$('.lowerFrontStripRow img').hover(         

function(){
     $('.orbit-caption-bottom#bottomThumb'+$(this).data("thumbid")).slideDown();

},

function(){

     $('.orbit-caption-bottom').slideUp();

}

);
```

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter of `.unbind()` is the `eventType` so:

```
$('.lowerFrontStripRow img').unbind('hover');
```

would be the right syntax to unbind your functions.

Btw probably you've to change the whole approach to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to want to do is:

Display if:

- The user hovers over an element

Disable if any of the following conditions are met:

- The user doesn't hover over the element anymore
- An x amount of time after the user started hovering over the element.

---

First of all, `hover(...)` is a shorthand for `.on( 'mouseover' )` and `.on( 'mouseout' )`; It actually binds those two events and you have to unbind those two events as well. You also seem to have problems with the mouseover function calling multiple times? Why not store some information on the element to prevent this?

```
$('.lowerFrontStripRow img').on( 'mouseover', function() {
    if( $(this).data( 'displaying' ) != 1 ) {
        $(this).data( 'displaying', 1 );
        $('.orbit-caption-bottom'+$(this).data("thumbid")).slideDown();
        setTimeout( function() { $('.orbit-caption-bottom').slideUp(); }, 3000 );
    }
} ).on( 'mouseout', function() {
    $(this).data( 'displaying', 0 );
    $('.orbit-caption-bottom'+$(this).data("thumbid")).slideUp();
} );
```